# Running asynchronous functions in non-asynchronous functions

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to run some asynchronous functions in her asynchronous function, the problem is, how did I understand that functions don't run like that, then how do I do it? I don't want to make the maze_move function asynchronous.

```
async def no_stop():
    #some logic
    await asyncio.sleep(4)

async def stop(stop_time):
    await asyncio.sleep(stop_time)
    #some logic

def maze_move():
    no_stop()
    stop(1.5)

async def main(websocket):
global data_from_client, data_from_server, power_l, power_r
get_params()
get_data_from_server()
get_data_from_client()
while True:
    msg = await websocket.recv()
    allow_data(msg)
    cheker(data_from_client)
    data_from_server['IsBrake'] = data_from_client['IsBrake']
    data_from_server['powerL'] = power_l
    data_from_server['powerR'] = power_r
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(data_from_server))
    print(data_from_client['IsBrake'])

start_server = websockets.serve(main, 'localhost', 8080)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: You edited your question and it is now less clear. It is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because I don't see from where you are trying to call `maze_move` (and you are missing import statements, function definitions (for example, `start_server`) and you have an indentation error).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```py
def maze_move():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(no_stop())
    loop.run_until_complete(stop(1.5))
```

If you wanted to run two coroutines concurrently, then:

```
def maze_move():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(no_stop(), stop(1.5)))
```

**Update Based on Updated Question**

I am guessing what it is you want to do (see my comment to your question):

First, you cannot call from `maze_move` coroutines such as `stop` directly since `stop()` does not result in calling `stop` it just returns a coroutine object. So `maze_move` has to be modified. I will assume you do not want to make it a coroutine itself (why not as long as you already have to modify it?). And further assuming you want to invoke `maze_move` from a coroutine that wishes to run concurrently other coroutines, then you can create a new coroutine, e.g. `maze_move_runner` that will run `maze_move` in a separate thread so that it does not block other concurrently running coroutines:

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

async def no_stop():
    #some logic
    print('no stop')
    await asyncio.sleep(4)

async def stop(stop_time):
    await asyncio.sleep(stop_time)
    print('stop')
    #some logic

async def some_coroutine():
    print('Enter some_coroutine')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('Exit some_coroutine')
    return 1

def maze_move():
    # In case we are being run directly and not in a separate thread:
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except:
        # This thread has no current event loop, so:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(no_stop())
    loop.run_until_complete(stop(1.5))
    return 'Done!'

async def maze_move_runner():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    # Run in another thread:
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, maze_move)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    results = await (asyncio.gather(some_coroutine(), maze_move_runner()))
    print(results)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```None
Enter some_coroutine
no stop
Exit some_coroutine
stop
[1, 'Done!']
```

But this would be the most straightforward solution:

```py
async def maze_move():
    await no_stop()
    await stop(1.5)
    return 'Done!'

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    results = await (asyncio.gather(some_coroutine(), maze_move()))
    print(results)
```

Comment: Although I did not specify this in the question, maze_move is not a function that is executed first, that is, at least the main function, which calls the maze_move function

Answer (score 0):

If you have an already running event loop, you can define an async function inside of a sync function and launch it as task:

```
def maze_move():
    async def amaze_move():
        await no_stop()
        await stop(1.5)
    return asyncio.create_task(amaze_move())
```

This function returns an `asyncio.Task` object which can be used in an await expression, or not, depending on requirements.  This way you won't have to make `maze_move` itself an async function, although I don't know why that would be a goal.  Only a async function can run `no_stop` and `stop`, so you've got to have an async function somewhere.